# I got exception when I run my C# console app on remote server - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, console-application

I wrote a small program in order to upload files from oracle to SharePoint online. It's running fine on my own local workstation. But it's can't be run on other local work station and remote servers. I got below exception when I published it as a self-contained application to remote desktop. I checked my firewall. Firewall is off on the remote server and local work station

Here are the code. I used print statement to check which line of code fail.

```
namespace sharepoint
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uploading...");
                Console.WriteLine("0");
                ServiceReference1.ServiceClient ws = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                ws.start_processAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("2");
                Console.WriteLine("Upload Finished!");
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is :

```
Uploading...
0
1
```

Then I got exception.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at sharepoint.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Temp\tmp\fire\SFFD\sharepoint\WebService\sharepoint\Program.cs:line 13
```

Here's the async method. It is auto generated from my webservice when I reference method startProcess() from my webservice to this console app.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    namespace ServiceReference1
    {
        using System.Runtime.Serialization;


        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1-preview-30310-0943")]
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CompositeType", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/")]
        public partial class CompositeType : object
        {

            private bool BoolValueField;

            private string StringValueField;

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public bool BoolValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.BoolValueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.BoolValueField = value;
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
            public string StringValue
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.StringValueField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.StringValueField = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1-preview-30310-0943")]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.IService")]
        public interface IService
        {

            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetDataResponse")]
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value);

            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetDataUsingDataContract", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetDataUsingDataContractResponse")]
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(ServiceReference1.CompositeType composite);

            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService/start_process", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/start_processResponse")]
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task start_processAsync();
        }

        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1-preview-30310-0943")]
        public interface IServiceChannel : ServiceReference1.IService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
        {
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.1-preview-30310-0943")]
        public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ServiceReference1.IService>, ServiceReference1.IService
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
            /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
            static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

            public ServiceClient() : 
                    base(ServiceClient.GetDefaultBinding(), ServiceClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
            {
                this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService.ToString();
                ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
            }

            public ServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                    base(ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), ServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
            {
                this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
                ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
            }

            public ServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
                    base(ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
            {
                this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
                ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
            }

            public ServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                    base(ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
            {
                this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
                ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
            }

            public ServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                    base(binding, remoteAddress)
            {
            }

            public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetDataAsync(int value)
            {
                return base.Channel.GetDataAsync(value);
            }

            public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.CompositeType> GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(ServiceReference1.CompositeType composite)
            {
                return base.Channel.GetDataUsingDataContractAsync(composite);
            }

            public System.Threading.Tasks.Task start_processAsync()
            {
                return base.Channel.start_processAsync();
            }

            public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
            {
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
            }

            public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
            {
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
            }

            private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
            {
                if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService))
                {
                    System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                    result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                    result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                    result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                    result.AllowCookies = true;
                    return result;
                }
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
            }

            private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
            {
                if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService))
                {
                    return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://localhost:53235/Service.svc");
                }
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
            }

            private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
            {
                return ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService);
            }

            private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
            {
                return ServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService);
            }

            public enum EndpointConfiguration
            {

                BasicHttpBinding_IService,
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us the code in the method to help us detect the error: ws.start_processAsync();

Comment: What is the address of the remote service?  It's apparently unavailable.

Comment: looks like the async method causes time out on remote server. However, if I don't put wait(), the method does nothing.

Comment: looks like the port number is not listening on my remote server. What should I do?